# Current carrying cable/busbar cooling ways in an aircraft

Tags: current, cables, copper, busbar

For an aircraft has an altitude 35000 feet, what'd it have to cool its cables/copper busbars up? High altitude means lower air density and it means lower oxygen, convection doesn't make sense and if I put aside a fan system, what else the ways would be to cool them up?

Comment: FWIW Air density will be less than 1/4 of sea level value. Within pressurised spaces air density will be somewhat more than 1/2 of sealevel value.  Cables will radiate just as well. Convection will be lower. There is quite a lot on web on this . I will post some 'comments' in an answer

Comment: @huytergan  Oxygen percentage of air is about the same at 35,000 feet as at sea level. The air itself is far less dense and the pressure is lower (as I imagine you are well aware). I would not expect Oygen level itself to affect the surface heat conduction - but, I may be wrong. Can you cite a reference that suggests that this is the case?

Comment: A major problem with this question is a lack of initial information. You have provided SOME more in comments - which makes it hard for people to find all the information, and it is clear that there is more that you could tell us that would help us provide you with better answers.  As full as possible (possibly limited by NDAs) a description should help a lot.

Comment: I wanted to keep the question short b/c thought details would have prevented people from digging up. Not everyone sees the same thing when they dig up. That's why.

Comment: Your choice. You can do as you have done and get the sort of results you have got. Or try what I suggest and see if it helps. Adding data does not HAVE to mean making the question too broad, although that is always a risk.

Comment: The oxide layer will usually form in a usual Oxygen atmosphere but not substantially diminish at lower oxygen levels. A black rough oxide finish is probably best fro radiation from bare copper - but I imagine insulation is usually present. For interest, where are you located? I'm in New Zealand.

Comment: Agreed! I'm in Turkey. Thanks for your comments, they helped much. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken to the extreme, consider how cooling is done on spacecraft that operate in a vacuum. Obviously, convection is not possible. Conduction just moves the heat around, which can be helpful but is not a complete solution.

The only remaining method is **radiation**. Large, black surfaces at high temperature radiate heat into space.

Comment: According to a book, as you already said Matt Black surfaces radiate and it’s a solution but how good is open to discussion. It says it saves current carrying capacity max up to 6%. What do you think about oxide layer?

Comment: What oxide layer are you talking about?? What is the emissivity of the oxide layer? If you are using radiative cooling then you make certain that the surfaces have a high emissivity, you don't just allow metals to oxidize at random.

Answer (score 1):

Mentions of cable related cooling at altitude are hard to find, alas.
However , the papers cited below relate to cooling at altitude and deal with the related issues in general.

Suggestions:

- Derate
- Fan or forced air flow (even though you would prefer not to).
- Increase thermally conductive paths - eg

  - Provide a metal frame or shell that adds thermal conductivity or radiating area.
  - Bond to metal surfaces with metallic "cable ties".

**________________**

[Garglabet image search - cable cooling at high altitude](https://www.google.com/search?q=cable+cooling+at+high+altitude&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwianLeW3friAhXOQ30KHTXkBmMQsAR6BAgBEAE&biw=1440&bih=708)

---

This paper relates to electronics rather than cables but looks useful. Note that they suggest that fan cooling is the easiest approach.

[Cooling Electronics at High Altitudes Made Easy](https://www.electronics-cooling.com/1998/09/cooling-electronics-at-high-altitudes-made-easy/)

---

**High-Altitude Considerations for Electrical Power Systems and Components**

Cable not mentioned but related factors discussed.

[**Slideshow:**](https://www.psma.com/sites/default/files/uploads/tech-forums-safety-compliance/presentations/is63-design-considerations-power-supplies-high-altitude-applications.pdf)

[Paper](http://outbackpower.force.com/servlet/fileField?id=0BE80000000GmtV)

---

[How does altitude affect AC-DC power supplies?](https://www.edn.com/electronics-blogs/power-supply-notes/4402833/How-does-altitude-affect-AC-DC-power-supplies-)

---

[Altitude and Electrical System Design](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/altitude-electrical-system-design-pavithran-karatha/)

Comment: Ever heard a conduction/liquid hybrids? I've heard it as a cooling way but applied for a bigger rectangular system on its wall, called as cold wall. Using a hollowed-out maze with liquid, put through the system's sides instead of having heat-fin. I wonder something could be done like that for busbars/cables or not?

Comment: @huytergan Conduction and liquid cooling don't eliminate the heat they just move it to another place in the system. If you run cold liquid through your wall then the heat from the liquid must be removed eventually, or the whole system just keeps getting hotter.

Comment: @huytergan  Liquid cooling is usually more complex than fan or other air cooling. You may also want to look at "heat pipes" which have excellent heat energy handling characteristics per size - they use phase change (boiling) inside at (usually) reduced pressure to tailor the target temperature to the user's requirements.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Nothing eliminates heat :-). Heat always just goes somewhere else. You knew that :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Yup, I should have said "...from your system..."

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I get it well, that’s what I thought exactly, why would I run hot liquid instead of cold. That’s already our purpose. But, I don’t think it’d be appropriate for cylindrical busbar.

Comment: @huytergan If you run cold water into the busbar it comes out as **hot water**. So now you have a lot of hot water to deal with rather than a hot busbar. I'm not sure you are thinking this through.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I am, But I thought it could be easy to provide it a ‘non-hot water ’ constantly. It’s not appropriate for busbar/cable tho A company’s ceo was introducing it as a cooling way but it’s was for their automatic target recognising system. Big and So different from busbar.